# GarageBand - Recover .band file

Tags: garageband

Many years ago I had an iPhone with GarageBand. I found in my iCloud account a .band archive which I downloaded. It's a folder with a few folders (Contents, Media, Output) and a file named projectData. I haven't got in my possession at the moment GarageBand or any Apple devices.

Is there a way to recover that song? I mean converting those archives into MP3, for example.